# ImageView cutted when dragging through the screen

Tags: android, imageview, drag

I'm making a project at school,  and I have this little character in a ImageView which is on overlay (the goal is to create a Shimeji for those who know what it is). 
I've been having a problem when dragging the ImageView through the screen.

[image: The image when it's on the screen] . 
[image: Then when I drag it around the screen]

So the image set in the ImageView is moving but it's cut off by the ImageView (at least I guess, because as soon as I move it around it's beginning to be cut off)

Here's my xml :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/Layout">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/View"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
         />

</FrameLayout>
```

Then my the way I add it to the screen :

```
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    view = new ImageView(this);
    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.idle);
    idleanimation = (AnimationDrawable)view.getBackground();
    idleanimation.start();

    view.setOnClickListener(new Click());
    view.setOnLongClickListener(new drag());

    li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.START;
    myview = li.inflate(R.layout.playground, null);
    wm.addView(view, params);
}
```

And then the way I drag it around the screen  :

```
 private class drag implements View.OnLongClickListener {
    float x,y;
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        view.setOnTouchListener(new action());
        return false;
    }

    private class action implements View.OnTouchListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                x=event.getX();
                y=event.getY();

                view.setX(x-81);
                view.setY(y - 100);
            break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I'd be glad to get some help in order to understand this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging all around the net I finally found something that helped me :

```
 case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                int x_cord = (int) event.getRawX();
                int y_cord = (int) event.getRawY();
                params.x= (x_cord-360);
                params.y =(y_cord-640);
                wm.updateViewLayout(view, params);

            break;
```

It was the window manager (wm), moving it instead of the view did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

please Set the ScaleType Like this In Imageview **android:scaleType="fitXY"**

```
  <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_height="100dp"/>
```

Comment: same problem here, any suggestions actually?

Comment: @SérgioS.Filho which type of problem

Comment: @NKmewara I have a png image with 2048px width, containing musical scores that is moving from right to left of the screen by changing the ImageView marginLeft. The option 'animateLayoutChanges' of the parent is marked as true. It's good enough for me but for just one device wich the screen is very small, the end of the image is cutted.